# Oracle Load from other Database Scenarios

Tags: oracle, database-connection, database-link

I am new in oracle (about 6 month ), 
I manage 2 Database, let say DB_A and DB_B, both is Oracle database, 
DB_A have Public database link to DB_B, 
this dbLink is used in package function to get data from DB_B and write it's data to a table DB_A.DailyValueOfB

that package function is called regularly(daily) by script in linux server using sqlplus command, combined with cron.

the problem is , that package function is currently is not writing anything because no input  , but the table DB_A.DailyValueOfB still have the most updated data.

I have tried finding using SQL Developer software
a. DBlink of DB_A in DB_B, in case DB_B access DB_A, but nothing found
b. I browse in each database, "scheduler" folder and it's subfolder, but nothing found
c. using this query

```
select *
    from SYS.ALL_SOURCE
   where UPPER(text) like '%@DBLINKNAME%';
```

i just found only on the package.function body i mentioned above.

d. I try part of package.function that accessing DB_B and it works properly get data from DB_B.

Is there any scenarios that I missing? 
Is there any way an oracle database accessing other oracle database beside using DBlink?

Thanks before

Comment: If possible provide the database link definition and the function definition.

Comment: So, let me try and boil this down.  You have pl/sql that is supposed to pull data from table from a remote DB to local DB and it is not writing anything, but the expected data exists in local DB.  So, you are looking for any other code that would be moving the data.  You can't find code in local DB using the link name.  So, how do you know the pl/sql in question is not doing the work?  Are you also looking at the remote DB as it could have its own link to the local DB and be pushing the data?